Extra whitespace in Help Center titles
The titles in the Help Center articles have both leading and trailing whitespace. For example, here's the HTML from How to Ask:
<h1 class="s-page-title--header">
                How do I ask a good question?
            </h1>

This adds extra leading and trailing spaces into the clipboard when copying the title. Steps to reproduce on Firefox 133.0:

Navigate to "How to Ask" or any other Help Center article.
Double-click the title ("How do I ask a good question?") or equivalent to highlight the whole thing.
CTRL+C
CTRL+V somewhere else. This should produce something like " How do I ask a good question? " - notice the space before "How" and after "question"

This is particularly annoying when trying to create hyperlinks. I often hyperlink to articles by title ([How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask), though I'd probably magic link in this particular case) - having to manually delete the leading and trailing spaces from the hyperlink text is frustrating.
Could this whitespace be removed? In this particular case, the HTML would look more like:
<h1 class="s-page-title--header">How do I ask a good question?</h1>


No repro in Chrome, it does add newline but no spaces.

I'm surprised they're not minifying the HTML, which would have incidentally solved this problem.

Just weighing in that html is largely white-space insensitive where multiple consecutive white spaces are typically rendered as a single space.  We have a lot of instances of page title header we'd need to consider. Some have no space; some do.  And I generally wouldn't want to make promises about how we produce whitespace in the rendered markup, especially without really strict linting to prevent regressions.

This sounds like a bug that needs to be fixed in Firefox, not by individual site authors.

Wow, looking at Firefox’s issue tracker, whitespace handling when copying seems to be an ongoing pain point going back 26 years. They fix one edge case then break another, and it takes years until someone works on it again and their fix breaks something else, and this just continues forever. Not good.

@Jeremy In an ideal world, I’d agree with you. But like you said, fixing this in Firefox could take forever. Slapping a band-aid on it here would take a couple minutes.

I wouldn't make this change. In my job at a different tech company, my team also currently uses an old templating system that doesn't remove whitespace, so the output has weird whitespace based on our template code formatting like Stack does. I still want our template code formatted consistently. This is one case, but to properly fix this in all cases would require re-formatting of every template, properly making it messier to read and edit, for the sake of a pretty minor bug in a browser used by a small minority. (Though we are gradually migrating to a better system. I wonder if Stack are.)
